# Exiting a for loop via try/catch

Tags: java

following is a portion of my code

```
if(search_result.contains(num_per_page_str)) { // if  num item per page is => 24,
   for(int item = 1 ; item <= num_per_page_int ; item++ ) { //interate over the current page 
      Thread.sleep(3000);
      try {//if display vertical + horizontal
         WebElement url = driver.findElement(By.linkText(item_desc)); // get the URL via element
         String item_URL = url.getAttribute("href"); 
         System.out.println("Item URL = " +  item_URL); 
         getPrice(driver, item_URL);                        
      } //try
      catch (Exception e) { //if display vertical only
         WebElement url = driver.findElement(By.linkText(item_desc)); // get the URL via element
         String item_URL = url.getAttribute("href");
         System.out.println("Item URL = " +  item_URL);
         getPrice(driver, item_URL);                        
      } //catch
   } // for int item = 1                
} //if search result
else { //if items per page < 24         
}//else
```

Once in the try/catch branch, upon reaching `getPrice(driver, item_URL);` , I expect it to call the getPrice function together with the arguements.

However, what I am getting now is upon executing the calling of the getPrice() function, it did not exit the for loop and re-iterates the loop.

Am I doing anything wrong in my code that blocks the exiting of for loop ? Thanks

Comment: You can move the try-catch such that it wraps around the loop. Then, when exiting the `catch` block, it will be outside. `try { for (...) { ... } } catch (...) { ... }`. You wont have the `item_URL` then anymore of course. You can also just use `break;` to exit the loop.

Comment: use `break` statement

Comment: @Zabuzard Thanks for the advice. Just wondering, is there any issue in my coding, so I can avoid it in the future ?

Comment: @B.M That seems like a good way. I will try that and update you.

Comment: Is it just me or `try` and `catch` blocks are exactly the same? What is the logic behind that? If `try` block fails then `catch` will fail as well, no?

Comment: Please elaborate a little bit more on what you want to achieve here. It is very unclear to me what it is meant to do.

Comment: @Amongalen YEs, they are executing the same thing...the difference is that when a certain item_desc is received, it run the try branch, and if hits a 'findElement is missing error', the catch will catch it and execute the item_desc in the catch block.

Comment: If it throws an exception in `try` block then it will do so in `catch` as well.

Comment: @Amongalen, the catch block has a code (which I removed to keep my question simple) that call on another site. I did not include it in my question because I assume the logic in the branch was irrelevant to my question of trying to exit the For loop. Apologies

Answer (score -2):

Add a break after calling getPrive, like:

```
    for(int item = 1 ; item <= num_per_page_int ; item++ ) { //interate over the current page 
      Thread.sleep(3000);
      try {//if display vertical + horizontal
         WebElement url = driver.findElement(By.linkText(item_desc)); // get the URL via element
         String item_URL = url.getAttribute("href"); 
         System.out.println("Item URL = " +  item_URL); 
         getPrice(driver, item_URL); 
         break;
                   
      } //try
      catch (Exception e) { //if display vertical only
         WebElement url = driver.findElement(By.linkText(item_desc)); // get the URL via element
         String item_URL = url.getAttribute("href");
         System.out.println("Item URL = " +  item_URL);
         getPrice(driver, item_URL);
         break;                        
      } //catch

   } // for int item = 1
```

Comment: with `finally { break; }` it will always break, even if there was no error at all. That means that the loop is obsolete as it will always only execute a single iteration only. Move the `break` into the `catch` block instead.

Comment: @Linh, my pologies. Maybe I miss out some info from my questions. What I need to do is that once I reach the getPrice() function, I need to exit from the for loop, go to the getPrice() to continue with some task, and then return back to the for loop. But thanks for your advice too.

Comment: From what I understand, the author wants to exit the loop once the getPrice in the try{} block is executed

Comment: @LinhNguyen Correct. But your code does not do that. `finally` executes always. In both cases, if `catch` was entered but **also** if catch was **not entered**.

Comment: You're right. break; should be added right after each getPrice()

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I shall try it and update you guys.

Comment: I am still getting a complete exit from the for loop. I added break; right after the getPrice(). My aim is after calling getPrice(), it should run the task in getPrice(), then return to the for loop for the next iteration.

Comment: hmm, then you don't have to do anything else. Unless there is something wrong before the getPrice() line. Like, is element url found and correct?